# when using kendo.drawing.exportPDF , text pasted from Word shows wrong

Tags: kendo-ui

All punctuations in the HTML that was brought over by pasting from MS word, show as a little square instead of " or '   The characters show as "FS" and "GS" in notepad++  `and`   in plain HTML.
I tried to use the  "DejaVu Sans" font but it did not help at all.
Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Ended replacing all offending characters.

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(str1, str2, ignore)
{
   return this.replace(new RegExp(str1.replace(/([\,\!\\\^\$\{\}\[\]\(\)\.\*\+\?\|\<\>\-\&])/g, function(c){return "\\" + c;}), "g"+(ignore?"i":"")), str2);
};
```

Then for each cell of text:

```
function cleanHTML(input) {
    var output = input.replaceAll('“','"');
    output = output.replaceAll('”', '"');
    output = output.replaceAll("’", "'"); 
    output = output.replaceAll("‘", "'");
    output = output.replaceAll("", "'");
    output = output.replaceAll("", "-");
    output = output.replaceAll("", "'");
    return output;
}
```

Whatever other charter will show as square later, I will add a replace for it.
Hope someone will benefit from that.